# I recommend or I'm recomending you something

Tags: present-tense, present-continuous, present-simple

Which is correct? When to use present simple and when present continuous. When I recommend / recommending something someone on StackExchange, which tense would be better and why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Both are correct**

The present  shows that you recommend something, and you may do it multiple times:

> I recommend this to my customers.
>
> I recommend that you use this.

The present continuous suggests that you recommend something at the time of speaking:

> I am recommending this to my customers.
>
> I'm recommending that you use this.

Both of these show that you are actively recommending something *right now* instead of in general.